# JS - regx allow only alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for alphanumeric regex expression that allow only alphabets. I have tried with this this code

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

But, it seem not work correctly. I'm looking for regex that allow only string below.

```
const str1 = 78;
const str2 = 'contains spaces';
const str3 = 'with symbols !@#$%^&';
const str4 = 'user78';
const str4 = 'khemvesna';

function alphanumeric(str) {
  const regx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
  return regx.test(str);
}

console.log(alphanumeric(str1)); // ️ false
console.log(alphanumeric(str2)); // ️ false
console.log(alphanumeric(str3)); // ️ false
console.log(alphanumeric(str4)); // ️ true
console.log(alphanumeric(str5)); // ️ true
```

Comment: Just clarifying, are you saying that `str1` should return `false` because it's an integer, not a string?

Comment: So, "78" is not allowed but "user78" is allowed?

Comment: yeah,  it what I want

Comment: it must required one characters

Comment: How about "3baz"?

Comment: this would be allow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only match strings that contain at least one **letter**, and contain nothing other than **letters/numbers**:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

```js
const str1 = 78;
const str2 = 'contains spaces';
const str3 = 'with symbols !@#$%^&';
const str4 = 'user78';
const str5 = 'khemvesna';

function alphanumeric(str) {
  const regx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
  return regx.test(str);
}

console.log(alphanumeric(str1)); // ️ false
console.log(alphanumeric(str2)); // ️ false
console.log(alphanumeric(str3)); // ️ false
console.log(alphanumeric(str4)); // ️ true
console.log(alphanumeric(str5)); // ️ true
```